# Application Stateful or Stateless

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

There is one web application created in java using Spring and Hibernate.

Application functionalities includes search, adding, view , update back button etc.

Is this application stateful or stateless.

I mean how to determine weather application is stateful or stateless.

Comment: If some variable defined in some class keeps its value from one request to another, then the application is not stateless.

Comment: VJS, have the answers been helpful? Can you updated your question if not?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a login to some data, you are already beginning to get into a stateful application. Since your login already needs some state.

Now you can narrow down your question, down to requests. And here is the same question. If you need some data from request to request, you have also some state.

Now the keyquestion. Do you need stateless or stateful session beans? It depends on your business needs. Better you fix your question to be more specific if this answer is not enough.

Comment: yes, there is a login form so this means application is statefull ?

Comment: as soon as you have a login, you have to manage the session/cookie of the user to match to specific rights/roles. So yes, it is stateful. But usually the developers talk about state if it is more than the crucial role/rights, which are mapped to a user.